# Access html document in one browser from another browser

Tags: javascript, dom

please could anyone point me in the right direction to solve the following problem:

Environment: Windows 8, Mozilla Firefox.

An html document is open in browser A. The content of another document, when opened in a separate browser B, must be dependent on the current value of a particular variable in the document of browser A. This value is needed to be read once, no bi-directional communication between browsers is required.

I can't figure out how to make javascript in one document access the DOM structure which resides in another browser and whether it's allowed at all. I've also looked at the possibility to use window.postMessage but it seems to be used only for messaging between windows within the same browser.

Thank you for any tips.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Browser to browser communication without a server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283716/browser-to-browser-communication-without-a-server) -- you won't be able to access the DOM of a page in another browser, but you can send messages.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible **by design**.

The only workaround - if applicable - is to make yourself a browser (or a browser-enveloper) to interact dinamically with page content at an application level.